# On Create Index, Invalid default value

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to create an index

```
create index userLoginInfo on user_login_info(created_at);
```

on the following table

```
+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table           | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user_login_info | CREATE TABLE `user_login_info` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `activity_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=261727 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

however, I am getting the following error

```
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'activity_time'
```

Using Server Version

```
5.7.20 Homebrew
```

Any ideas on how I can create this index?

Comment: It was imported, I am asking now what version created the dump...

Comment: it has something to do with sql_modes...

Comment: I was able to run the statement after executing `SET sql_mode = '';`

Comment: @JeffreyL.Roberts - setting `sql_mode=''` with MySQL is nothing short of **madness** - you'll get non-standard (i.e. **wrong**) behaviour (with `GROUP BY` for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)!

> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and
>   time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to
>   '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

You are exceeding the permitted ranges! Also, should `activity_time` be a duration of some sort? Maybe a `begin_timestamp` and `end_timestamp` might be an idea?

You should prefer `TIMESTAMP` to `DATETIME`, from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html) (`Date and Time Type Storage Requirements`), a timestamp without fractional seconds (i.e. most of them)  requires only 4 bytes (as opposed to 5, but hey!). Also, 99% of dates that we deal with on a day to day basis will be between 1970 and 2038.

[This part](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html) of the manual should help with initialisations.

Following the small oversight so kindly pointed out by @ypercubeᵀᴹ I had a look at this issue - i.e. of '0000-00-00 00:00:00' being a `special "zero" value`.

The fruits of my efforts are available [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cmwR9a7RcnvreXbQ1JSN38/4).

`DDL`:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_login_info` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  -- `activity_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  -- FAILS
  `test_time1` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,  -- WORKS
  -- `test_time2` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', -- FAILS
  -- `test_time3` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,  -- FAILS
  -- `test_time35` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `test_time4` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `test_time5` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01, 00:00:01', -- FAILS with time = 00:00:00
  -- `test_dtime6` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  -- FAILS
  `test_time6` TIMESTAMP NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  -- `test_time7` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  -- 'test_time8` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  -- FAILS
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX my_index (created_at) -- if the TABLE is CREATEd, the INDEX is!
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

It appears to me that there is a problem/bug with MySQL - in that it appears to confuse this special "zero" with the `NULL` value! It won't work with `DATETIME` either! I looked at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html) again and can't appear to find why many of the failing constructs in my DDL won't work. There was a time when MySQL didn't work with multiple `TIMESTAMP`s - maybe this is relic of that epoch? I even tried [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa8148/1) - which will build the schema but then fails - not sure why! I hope this clarifies matters unless @ypercubeᵀᴹ has a better suggestion! I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851672/one-mysql-table-with-multiple-timestamp-columns) helpful.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - I looked at these issues (thanks for the heads up!) and you are correct in the first instance - the **documentation** seems to indicate that what the OP was trying to do **should** work, but it doesn't! I think there's some problem with `0000-00-00 00:00:00` being taken for `NULL`? As for the `INDEX` not being created, this works no problem if the table can be created. Difficult to put an `INDEX` on a table that's not been created? :-)

Comment: If you use `sql_mod = ''`, I'm sure that the server could get the sun to rise in the west! I used to get caught on the `GROUP BY` nonsense! Unfortunately, in biology (my area), many people have used MySQL when they should have used PostgreSQL and are now  paying the price - it's a bit like a dysfunctional relationship - easy to fall into, hard to get out of! Lesson learnt! :-(

Answer (score -2):

If possible, replace `timestamp` with `datetime` first. Then reindex.

Comment: First, the issue here is in the same column - activity_time. Ideally, you should have have only one timestamp per table auto initialized, because that records when your record was added or updated. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html will let you know that the default value provided is out of range.